# Can not login Window Partner center Dashboard

Tags: windows, authentication, block, store, dashboard

Today I login my dashboard see  a message box pop up.
I click accept , but still lock at the box.
I reopen the web browser, but still block at the message box.
Cannot go into Dashboard.
And can not submit my app to Store.
What should I do in order to go into dashboard? 
Please help me.

https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/windows/overview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After I enable "Insider-Preview" switch, it is fixed.
The agreement popup is disappearing now.